# how to join two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables as **EventTable** and **VenueTable**

I m Using prinamrykey of each other as foreignkey. Table structure is as follows ;

```
EventID|VenueID|EventName 
    1  |    1  | Event1 
    2  |    1  | Event2 
    3  |    2  | Event3 


VenueId|EnevtID|VenueNAme
   1   |   1   | Venue1 
   2   |   2   | Venue2
```

and i want the result as follows ;

```
VenueID | VenueName | EventID | EventName
   1    | Venue1    |  1      | Event1 
   1    | Venue1    |  2      | Event2 
   2    | Venue2    |  2      | Event2
   2    | Venue2    |  3      | Event3
```

I have used inner join to do this., but could not get the expected result.

How to do this ?

Thanks..

Comment: Select v.VenuId,V.VenueName,E.EventId,E.EventName FROM Event  E INNER JOIN  Venue  V   ON E.EventID =V.EventID

Comment: I think that tables that you have mentioned above has something wrong/missing. In EventTable, eventId 2 is at venue 1 and in VenueTable, venueId 2 has event 2. Moreover, in your expected result you have mentioned that EventId 2 has two venues which contradicts with the above tables.

Comment: @rohanpanchal - Your query looks fine. As Bhavik mentions, your table may be missing a record.

Comment: As per me, your table structure is not correct. You see, you have distributed the VenueId and EventId relationship to two tables.
The relation for VenueId = 2 and EventId = 2 is mapped in Venue table but not in Events Table.
It is better you restructure table and put all the events in events table, map the relation between eventId and VenueId in EventsTable and let only VenueId and VenueName in Venue Table. That way, the join query would be easier to implement and get you the desired results.

Comment: @ Bhivik shah  -Yes EventID 2 has 2 Venue i.e Venue1 and Venue2 Event table Reffer venue1 and Venuetable Reffer EvnetID 2 that is Venue 2 so how to join both this ???

Comment: i need to join both table for VenueID and EventID Is it Possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    v.VenueID,
    v.VenueName,
    v.EventID,
    e.EventName
FROM
    VenueTable v
INNER JOIN
    EventTable e 
    ON (v.EventId = e.EventId)

UNION

SELECT
    v.VenueID,
    v.VenueName,
    v.EventID,
    e.EventName
FROM
    VenueTable v
INNER JOIN
    EventTable e 
    ON (v.VenueID = e.VenueID)
```

*This emulates a FULL OUTER JOIN in MySQL*

Comment: **MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FULL OUTER JOIN **

Comment: There is no `FULL OUTER JOIN` in the above query. Try again - copy only the script in the code block.

Comment: @rohan - As Sumit mentions in his comment to your question, you should really consider changing the design of your tables. It's not a good idea to store both keys in both tables without creating a composite key out of them.

Comment: @ Nicrus -i know but i am can't change design of table bcs it will affect on page code and need to change so much in project which working fine till now only one thing is this i need to change.

Comment: OK. Does my script help you?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
 select VenueID, VenueName, EventID, EventName
    from EventTable, VenueTable
    where EventTable.VenueID = VenueTable.VenueID
```

remember delimiter for mysql

Comment: USE **ANSI JOIN** instead of traditional JOIN

Comment: Why does this fix the OP's issue? If there are two tables and the most records either of them have is 3 - then the most records you will return with an INNER JOIN is 3...

Comment: i interpreted op as a request for a query to get the result, not as a must to use inner join, either op has to clarify his question or i dont see a purpose with your comment?

Comment: It's the same query, just in ANSI form from what the OP created. The result is the issue, not the style of the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT v.VenueID, v.VenueName, v.EventID, e.EventName
FROM VenueTable v
INNER JOIN EventTable e  ON (v.EventId = e.EventId)
```

Or even

```
SELECT v.VenueID, v.VenueName, v.EventID, e.EventName
FROM VenueTable v, EventTable e 
WHERE v.EventId = e.EventId
```